# Storing iterated values in a multi-dimensional list

Tags: python-3.x

Supposing I have a nested for loop -

```
for i in range(1,A):
    for j in range(1,B):
        for k in range(1,C):
            if abs(MyArray[i,j,k]) > threshold:
            continue
```

I want to store the values of `i,j,k` in the format of `[[i1,j1,k1],[i2,j2,k2]...]` for each value that satisfied the condition. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to options. With for loop:

```py
results = []
for i in range(1, A):
    for j in range(1, B):
        for k in range(1, C):
            if abs(MyArray[i, j, k]) > threshold:
                results.append((i, j, k))
```

With list comprehension

```py
results = [
  (i, j, k)
  for i in range(1, A)
  for j in range(1, B)
  for k in range(1, C)
  if abs(MyArray[i, j, k]) > threshold
]
```

Comment: That works splendidly! I am sorry if the question was repeated (to whoever downvoted it.) The problem is that often it is not possible to express correctly what one wants and sometimes it is hard to find solutions because they are worded differently.